# How to create permanent controls in asp.net codebehind

Tags: asp.net, web-applications

I have to add some controls to my project master page in code behind,but I want to keep them even after post back.how can i do this? I've searched about it and I think that i have to use preinit ,but I don't Know how, and I don't know if master Page has preinit.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="MainScriptmanager" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true" />
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="MasterContentUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TabContainer ID="MainTabContainer" runat="server" ActiveTabIndex="1" TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
            </asp:TabContainer>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>


  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabCount = tabCount + 1;
        AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tab = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
        tab.ID = "tab" + Convert.ToString(tabCount);
        tab.HeaderText = "tab" + Convert.ToString(tabCount);
        MainTabContainer.Tabs.Add(tab);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What keeps you from creating the controls and adding it to a, say, panel, in code behind? Create a panel in designer, name it, and create/add all the controls to in code behind wherever you need. Viewstate will preserve their contents between postbacks, you don't need to do anything extra.

Comment: I've tried it , but it doesn't work.let me explain : I have a ribbon bar and a tab container in may master page.I want to add a related tab in tab container by clicking on each item in ribbon (clicking on ribbon bar items make a post back) and I want to keep old tabs.

Comment: if you want to avoid postback at all:
1. you can pre populate all the related tabs at server side initially and make them appear at clientside via js.
2. or you can create the tabs dynamically completely by js (if no data from server is required)
3. you can use asp.net's ajax functionality to only update the relevant parts of your page without a full page postback.

i can't tell which is the best without knowing the exact scenario you are facing.

Comment: there is no way to re-add each previously added tab through the page's OnInit ?

Comment: i don't remember oninit but you obviously can do it in page_load

Comment: but after postback I don't have previous tabs anymore.

Comment: did you disable view state?

Comment: no I didn't. I tried to keep old tabs in a session and after post back add those to tabcontainer again. but it make this error:Script controls may not be registered after PreRender. I don't use PreRender at all but I think it used in AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel

Comment: if you are on ajax, you shouldn't be needing to re-add the controls on any postback or callback. if they are inside the panel that is handled by ajax, you shoudn't be re-adding them. try to examine what happens to your controls in the postback/callback at serverside.

Comment: I tried a simpler and it doesn't work too.I edited my question and add my new codes.this show one tab after each postback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recreate the tabs on each postback.

E.g. you might store the count of tabs in ViewState.

Then on PostBack, you add the tabs e.g. in your Page_Load event handler:

```
var tabCount = ... get it from ViewState
for(int i=0; i<tabCount; i++)
{
    AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel tab = new AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel();
    tab.ID = "tab" + Convert.ToString(i+1);
    tab.HeaderText = "tab" + Convert.ToString(i+1);
    MainTabContainer.Tabs.Add(tab);
}
```

Comment: yes, but my tab's header and content template aren't simple like this. I keep my tabs in a session and after each postback I tried to recreate them by using The session. and I face this error:Script controls may not be registered after PreRender.notably I could solve my problem by create a new class with tree properties that fill with tab's Id,headerTemplate,contentTemplate and keep it in session, it works fine but I prefer to keep entire tabs in session because it doesn't need to recreate all old tabs after each postback and only need to add old tabs to tabcontainer,but it doesn't work anyway

Comment: "I prefer to keep tabs in session" - but that's the wrong way to go about it, since, as you say, it doesn't work.  Instead, recreate controls on each postback.